# JQuery DataTable Headers Not Aligned With ScrollY and ServerSide Processing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have a MVC/Bootstrap 4 site with jquery datatable that is diplayed as an empty table on initial page load and then am using serverside processing to retrieve data in docReady function. Once the ajax returns with the data the column headings are slightly off. The first column header seems to be aligned correctly but then each of the following columns are all slightly off more than the previous column. At the end of the row it appears that the column headers are off by enough to display the vertical scroll bar even though its not actually displayed.

If I minimize/resize the browser window, then it redraws the headers and everything looks perfect, then if I maximize the window it also redraws the headers and looks perfect.

How can I force a redraw after the ajax call to get the data so headers are aligned with the columns. If the data returned causes the vertical scrollbar to display then the headers are off that much more. But if I manually resize the window it all redraws and fixes the issue.

Here is my dataTable:

```
 var dt = $('#data-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        dataSrc: 'list',
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        deferLoading: 0,
        bRetrieve: true,
        iDisplayLength: 50,
        scrollY: "500px",
        scrollCollapse: true,
        autoWidth: true,
        ajax: {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Equipment/LoadEquipmentListingGrid', 
            error: function(e) {
                console.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(e.message));
            }
        },
        order: [[3, "asc"]],
        columns: [
            {"data": "EQUIPMENT_ID"},
            { "data": "DESCRIPTION" },
            { "data": "MANUFACTURER" },
            { "data": "MODEL" },
            { "data": "SERIAL_NUMBER" },
            { "data": "EQUIPMENT_TYPE" }],
        ...
```

Here is the table:

```
<table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered mt-5">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Equipment Id</th>                
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Serial Number</th>
            <th>Equipment Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I tried adding a success attribute in the ajax call with a redraw but it doesnt work and just made another call to the server which I dont want/need. Just need the headers to redraw based on the new data in the table and if vertical scrollbar displayed or not (like it does on browser resize).

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to have the table redraw without making call to server. I added the "complete" attribute to the ajax call that retrieved the data for the table. In that "complete" function I just shrunk/resized the width of the containing DIV of the datatable and that allowed the headers to size correctly for the table:

```
 var dt = $('#data-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        dataSrc: 'list',
        dom: 'lBfrtip', 
        deferLoading: 0,
        bRetrieve: true,
        iDisplayLength: 50,
        scrollY: "500px",
        scrollCollapse: true,
        ajax: {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Equipment/LoadEquipmentListingGrid', //  "/Equipment/Index",
            error: function(e) {
                console.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(e.message));
            },
            complete: function() {
                var w = $('#MainEquipDiv').width();
                $('#MainEquipDiv').width(w - 1); // THIS IS THE FIX
                $('#MainEquipDiv').width(w + 1);            
            }
        },
        order: [[3, "asc"]],
```